# Number of ways of assigning n objects to k people such that each person has at least r?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, stirling-numbers

The closest I have found to this is the Stirling numbers of the second kind that is the number of ways of assigning n objects to k people such that each person has at least 1? How do I add the constraint that each person should have at least r objects?

Comment: Are you distinguishing the objects? If so, it is complicated

Comment: If the objects are indistinguishable, just assign $r$ to each of them and then distribute the $n-kr$ remaining objects to the $n$ people without restrictions.

Comment: Look for Associated Stirling numbers of the second kind. For example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08138.pdf